# AdSense Management API: Is there a way to get report by app id?

Tags: admob, adsense-api

I see we can filter by AD_CLIENT_ID and AD_UNIT_ID, but i do not see a dimension called APP_ID to filter by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see list of all dimensions and matrics here:

[image]

You can see that there is an APP_ID and APP_NAME dimension for GMOB product

Make sure you use the most recent api version and that reporting is enabled for you

Comment: I am able to get APP_NAME, but getting "0:" as APP_ID.

Comment: @SangamShankar that's weird, but I guess you can filter by APP_NAME that's can be good enough. Please mark it as the correct answer if it meets your need

Comment: I can filter by APP_NAME, but I am not getting what I am missing since I am getting "0:" as APP_ID. Anyways Thanks for the response.

Comment: Please have a look at this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42363783/adsense-management-api-getting-0-as-app-id-in-response