# AdSense Management API: Getting "0:" as APP_ID in response

Tags: adsense, adsense-api, admob

Request

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/adsense/v1.4/accounts/pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXX/reports?endDate=2019-01-01&startDate=2014-01-01&dimension=APP_ID&metric=INDIVIDUAL_AD_IMPRESSIONS&fields=headers%2C%20rows
```

Response

```
{ "headers": [ { "name": "APP_ID", "type": "DIMENSION" }, { "name": "APP_NAME", "type": "DIMENSION" }, { "name": "INDIVIDUAL_AD_IMPRESSIONS", "type": "METRIC_TALLY" } ], "rows": [ [ "0:", "abcdAndroidDemo_P1V1", "375" ], [ "0:", "abcdDemo", "13" ], [ "0:", "abcdiOSDemo", "34" ] ] }
```

How to get the APP_IDs of all the apps of publisher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting APP_ID after publishing the app in the app store.

Comment: This is not a publishing case. Api need linked app.  APP_ID is The app store ID or bundle ID of an application. Prefixed with 1: for iOS and 2: for Android. Examples: 1:476954712, 2:com.labpixies.lineup.